# How do I verify a hash code exists in MySQL table using Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to be able to verify comfirm row with specific hashcode exists in a table before a user bearing the given hash code can fill a registration form.

I know the hash code exists because it's in the database. But the application redirect to the page it should if the hash code is non-existent and outputs a message that the hash code doesn't exist.

This used to work in Laravel 5 but it seems the implementation has changed since Laravel 8.

Here's my code:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Site\Guest\newMembership\RegistrationForm;
```

...

```
Route::get('registration/{hashCode}', [RegistrationForm::class, 'registrationForm'])->name('registration');

    Route::post('registration', [RegistrationForm::class, 'registrationProcessing'])->name('registration_data');
```

My controller, RegistrationForm.php has the code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site\Guest\newMembership;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegistrationForm extends Controller
{
    public function registrationForm($hashCode)
    {
        // Check if this $hashCode exists at all, otherwise redirect to referral request home page.
        $hash_exists = (new \App\Http\Controllers\Site\Guest\newMembership\Form)->hashExists($hashCode);

        // In the event the number of times it occurs is zero
        if($hash_exists < 1)
        {
            // Tell user the referral link is non-existent.
            session()->flash('membershipInfo', 'Your code does not exist.');

            // Take this user to the referral request welcome page
            return redirect()->route('membership.index');
        }

        // Assign new variable name to hash code
        $referralCode = $hashCode;

        return view('membership.registration', [
            'referralCode' => $referralCode,
        ]);
    }
```

The Form contoller has the code:

```
// Import database model
use App\Models\Site\Guest\Referralrequestapplication;
```

...

```
   /**
     * Count number of entries with given ID
     */
    public function hashExists($hashCode)
    {
        //DB::table('referralrequestapplications')
        Referralrequestapplication::where(['blocked', 0], ['image_reference', $hashCode])->count();
    }
```

The model code:

```
namespace App\Models\Site\Guest;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Referralrequestapplication extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'blocked', 'review', 'reviewer', 'firstname', 'surname', 'phone', 'email', 'nin', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram', 'state', 'city', 'neighbourhood', 'address', 'image_reference', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'referralrequestapplications';
}
```

The migration schema has the code:

```
Schema::create('referralrequestapplications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->boolean('blocked')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('reviewed')->default(0);
            $table->string('reviewer')->nullable();

            $table->string('firstname', 30)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 30)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone', 30)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('nin', 20)->nullable();
            $table->string('facebook', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('twitter', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('instagram', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('state', 40)->nullable();
            $table->string('city', 40)->nullable();
            $table->string('neighbourhood', 40)->nullable();
            $table->string('address', 200)->nullable();
            $table->string('image_reference', 200)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the code in Form controller from:

```
Referralrequestapplication::where(['blocked', 0], ['image_reference', $hashCode])->count();
```

To:

```
Referralrequestapplication::where('blocked', 0)->where('mage_reference', $hashCode)->exists();
```

Also I changed the following in RegistrationForm controller:

```
if($hash_exists < 1)
```

To:

```
if($hash_exists = 0)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `=` is the correct operator in `if($hash_exists = 0)`?